# Reading data from firebase onDatachange

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Hello this is a sample application to save the data and read the data from FireBase and put it and listview with a adapter i don't have any problem with saving the data my problem is Reading it after the save with fucntion (onDataChange) i can't find the where is there error !

```
class ShowData : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var Ref:DatabaseReference
    lateinit var MyList:MutableList<ListData>
    lateinit var adapter:ListDataAdabter
    lateinit var myview:ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_data)
        MyList= mutableListOf()
        myview=findViewById(R.id.listview)
        LoadData()
        adapter= ListDataAdabter(MyList,this)
        myview.adapter=adapter
    }

    fun LoadData(){
        Ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyTexts")
        Ref.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ShowData,"Error witj your Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
                if (p0!!.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(this@ShowData,"The Data is Here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    MyList.clear()
                    for (e in p0.children){
                        val values = e.getValue(ListData::class.java)
                        MyList.add(values!!)
                    }
                }
            }

        })

    }
}
```

List Adapter

```
class ListDataAdabter(List:MutableList<ListData>,mCtx:Context): BaseAdapter() {
    var ListLocal = List
    var context = mCtx

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val item = ListLocal[p0]
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_type,null)
        view.TV_Fname.text=item.Fname
        view.TV_Lname.text=item.Lname
        view.TV_Age.text=item.Age
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return ListLocal[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return ListLocal.size
    }

}
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: the view window crash and close the application i don't get the saved data

Comment: what's the exception when your app crashes?

Comment: i don't know why the app it's never called the onDataChange function i don't get any Toast

Comment: you need to provide more information.  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: only crash like : Unfortunately, The App Has stopped

Comment: how can get more infomartion about my error cuz this is the problem

Comment: @Charaf try [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Comment: There is no error in the log

Comment: If there is a crash, these is for sure an error in your logcat, which is?

Comment: i can't run the app with my phone from android studio i was building the app then try it cuz that i don't get any error  Error running app: No target device found. i am trying to fix this